# To prove $AE$ bisects $\angle BAC$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, angle

In the figure below, given that $DE\:$ bisects $\angle BDF$ and $FE\:$ bisects $\angle DFC$. Prove that $AE\:$ bisects $\angle BAC$.
[image]

My try:
I dropped perpendiculars from $E$ to $DB$ and $FC$. But could not figure out.

Comment: hint: the dropped perpendiculars are equal

Comment: To prove that the two dropped perpendiculars are equal, drop another perpendicular from $E$ to $DF$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop altitudes from E to AB, DF and AC, with respective feet X, Y and Z.

The right triangles DXE and DYE are congruent; so are FYE and FZE, Thus, EX = EY = EZ and EXA and EZA are congruent, hence the angle bisector AE.

Answer (score 1):

$E$ is an *excentre* of $\triangle ADF$ -- it is the centre of a circle tangent to all three sides, as
$$\operatorname{dist}(E,\overline{AC})=\operatorname{dist}(E,\overline{DF})=\operatorname{dist}(E,\overline{AB}).$$

So automatically we get that $AE$ bisects $\angle DAF$.

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as the others, but with different words:

The circle with center at $E$ that has $AB$ and $DF$ as tangents (which exists because $DE$ is a bisector) is necessarily the same as the circle that has center at $E$ with $AC$ and $DF$ as tangents.

Thus there is a circle centered at $E$ with both $AB$ and $AC$ as tangents, so $AE$ bisects the angle between those lines.